# WebView2 - How to silently print a pdf file?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, webview2

After navigating to a pdf file (local file), I am running the following code which should send the current document to the default printer:

```
CoreWebView2Environment webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync();

CoreWebView2PrintSettings printerSettings = webView2Environment.CreatePrintSettings();

CoreWebView2PrintStatus printStatus =
    await webView2.CoreWebView2.PrintAsync(
        printerSettings
    );
```

My default printer is "Microsoft Print to PDF".

The print status is Succeeded and a pdf is created but it is entirely blank. When I print a local jpeg file it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/3007 and it might get fixed in a few sprints. I am currently looking for a work around.

Comment: I'm still getting this sporadically on WebView2 runtimes 117.*.* and above.  PrintAsync() says "Succeeded" but still a blank PDF.